# Shopify checkout styling

Tags: css, shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I do not know if I am missing something, but how would I go about to design a checkout page on the skeleton theme? I understand if I am unable to change certain things, but I need to be able to style the background and add the site logo along with a few other things.

Then help is definitely appreciate as always!

Answer (score 4):

You can add `checkout.css` or `checkout.css.liquid` to your assets. This file will be loaded on the checkout page(s). Also see the Shopify Manual on [Checkout CSS](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/develop-theme-layouts-checkout-scss-liquid).

**EDIT**

As @graygilmore commented, for mobile devices Shopify uses `checkout.mobile.css` or `checkout.mobile.css.liquid`.

Comment: Don't forget about this bit, too: "For mobile themes, you can overwrite the default checkout CSS by creating a file called “checkout.mobile.css” or “checkout.mobile.css.liquid”."

Comment: This is the best answer, and to address the specific question of Skeleton - you can't use the Skeleton framework on the checkout page because you don't have access to the code for that page, only the styling.

Comment: Small note that checkout theme (liquid)/css customizations are available to Shopify Plus ($2k/month) customers only now...